# Bash find not including paths?

Tags: bash, find

Just like the title says,

```
domain='foo.com'

find . -iregex '.*\(html\|htm\)' -printf '%f\0' | \
xargs -0 sed -Ee "s:(http|https)\://(www.|)${domain}::g" 

# sed: can't read index.html: No such file or directory
```

I am expecting

```
directory/directory/index.html
```

Not sure whats going on with find?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual page](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/find.1.php) says:

```
%f     File's name with any leading  directories  removed  (only
       the last element).
```

Comment: One upped and waiting to accept, should have used `%P` instead

Answer (score 1):

Use "%h%f" to get the full path (relative to the current path).

```
find . -iregex '.*\(html\|htm\)' -printf '%h%f\0'
```